# How to allow users to edit dynamic slim page templates in production for rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, view

Essentially I'm trying to implement a way so that users can edit slim that is stored in the database.

For example they would use the form to create a new page and insert the html for that page in a text field which would be saved in the database. I want to allow them to edit that page in slim. By the way the html stored is  slim not plain html.

If I store slim in the database how do I get rails to render the html properly on the client side in production? So in other words would rails automatically do this since the view is being render like so:

views/page/view.html.slim

```
  page.header 
  page.content
  page.footer
```

or would I have to figure out a way to convert on the fly? I might be making this more complicated then I should but I'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to convert the slim to Html and output that in your views.

This is directly from slims doc. This is how it processes slim files and outputs it.

```
Tilt.new['template.slim'].render(scope)
Slim::Template.new('template.slim', optional_option_hash).render(scope)
Slim::Template.new(optional_option_hash) { source }.render(scope)
```

so in short

```
Slim::Template.new(page/view.html.slim).render
```

put that in a module to make it prettier and I think you're good. You may want to use rails path helper to get the direct link for the view. You may also want to consider figuring out a way to catch the errors in indentation so that your output doesn't bug out in production. Some kind of validation that prevents it from saving if not properly formatted should help.